# What is the proper way to use linq Group operators to Flatten Query Results

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate

This is structure of data, I get back from NHibernate Query

```
public Class PaperResult 
{
    public Guid SubjectId {get;set}

    public Guid StudentId {get;set}

    public string Name {get;set}

    public string Email {get;set}

    public int Marks {get;set}

}
```

and my queries is

> 1. var resultEntities =  _repository.Query<PaperResult>().where(t => t.Id == testId)
> 2. studentResults = resultEntities.GroupBy(x => x.StudentId)

which returns, IQueryable, Now I'm projecting it into the class

```
public Class StudentResult 
{
    public Guid StudentId {get;set}

    public string Name {get;set}

    public string Email {get;set}

    public int Marks {get;set}

    public IEnumerable<PaperResult> PaperResults {get;set;}
}
```

I have tried to flatten the result using linq  below but Nhibernate is throwning **"The method or operation is not implemented."**.

```
from paperResult in studentResults
let studentResult  = paperResult.First()
select new StudentResult()
{
    StudentId =studentResult.StudentId,
    Name =studentResult.Name,
    Email =studentResult.Email,
    Marks =studentResult.Marks,
    PaperResults =resultEntities.Where(x => x.StudentId ==studentResult.StudentId
                  select new PaperResult(){...}.ToList()
}
```

Note: the code is a skeletal code.

Regards,

Comment: You have do resultEntities.toList(). Before mapping object to StudentResult.

Comment: Generally the 'correct' way to flatten data structures within LINQ is via the SelectMany() operator. You should certainly take a look at it, whether this is supported via Nhibernate i am not sure. :)

Comment: @HemantMalpote doing ToList() on deferred result will fetch data in memory which i want to avoid as it causes performance issues.

Comment: @DotNetHitMan any references pls ??

Comment: @SrinivasRa - http://blogs.interknowlogy.com/2008/10/10/use-linqs-selectmany-method-to-flatten-collections/ is a good article. If you need an example with your data I could knock one up.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do a projection to an anonimous type.

Then project to your desired type:
q.AsEnumerable().Select(...)